# How can I use sequelize in a Nodejs application that is using heroku postgresql database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, sequelize.js

I am creating a simple CRUD API using Nodejs, express. I need to use postgresql hosted on heroku for this app and Sequelize as ORM. However interaction with database is not working.
Here is my code
index.js

```
const express = require('express')
require('dotenv').config()
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const usersRouter = require('./routers/users')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
})

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
  })
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Nodejs mentoring 2022!')
})
app.use('/users', usersRouter)
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

/router/users

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
connst {
  getAllUsers
} = require('./controllers/userControllers')

//user routes
router
  .route('/')

  .get(getAllUsers)


module.exports = router
```

userControllers

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
})
const User = require('./../../models/user')(sequelize)
const createError = require('http-errors')

exports.getAllUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.findAll()
    if (!users) throw new createError.NotFound()
    res.status(200).send(users)
  } catch (e) {
    next(e)
  }
}
```

models/user

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize')

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false
      },
      login: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      age: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
      },
      is_deleted: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      timestamps: false
    }
  )
  return User
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-mentoring-2022",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/mamuna36/nodejs-mentoring-2022.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines" : {
    "node": "16.14.2"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mamuna36/nodejs-mentoring-2022/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mamuna36/nodejs-mentoring-2022#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-joi-validation": "^5.0.1",
    "joi": "^17.6.3",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.25.3",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.2"
  }
}
```

when I try to test the getAllUsers endpoint in postman I get this error

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "login", "password", "age", "is_deleted" FROM "Users" AS     "User";
Error
at Query.run (C:\Users\Mamuna_Anwar\VScodeProjects\nodejs-mentoring- 2022\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:50:25)
at C:\Users\Mamuna_Anwar\VScodeProjects\nodejs-mentoring-2022\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:314:28
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async PostgresQueryInterface.select (C:\Users\Mamuna_Anwar\VScodeProjects\nodejs-mentoring-2022\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:407:12)
at async Function.findAll (C:\Users\Mamuna_Anwar\VScodeProjects\nodejs-mentoring-2022\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1134:21)
at async exports.getAllUsers (C:\Users\Mamuna_Anwar\VScodeProjects\nodejs-mentoring-2022\routers\controllers\userControllers.js:39:19)
```

Comment: Is there more detail in the error message? Have you migrated your database on Heroku?

Comment: Hi Chris, there is no more details in the error message. I am using the Heroku postgresql add-on in my heroku app and I have created user table there using sql script in DBeaver.